# C# - Get uSNCreated value from AD - DomainController class (Casting System.__ComObject to string)

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

i used the code like

```
object getCreatedUSN=**objDC**.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["uSNCreated"].Value;
```

for getting the uSNCreated property value from C# - `DomainController **objDC**` class, but this object will return like `System.__ComObject`.

How can i casting this and how to get uSNCreated property value as string or object ??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.ToString()` on the end?